# Is there an updated solution for this problem?

Tags: flutter

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0] on DefaultConfig$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=21, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=30, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=1, versionName=1.0.0, applicationId=com.example.fyen, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=[], buildConfigFields={}, resValues={}, proguardFiles=[], consumerProguardFiles=[], manifestPlaceholders={applicationName=android.app.Application}, wearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig$AgpDecorated.

I have the same problem in every project.

Comment: Try clearing flutter cache by running this command: "flutter clean"